# How to build a sliding wall section

Tags: walls, interior, sliding-glass-door

A typical interior door is about 30" wide. Double doors (eg. French doors) could make that wider, up to maybe 60". But I'd like to build a sliding wall section, perhaps 90-120" wide in place of an interior wall.

I imagine something like a sliding glass door (some people call them "sliders"), but made of some typical interior wall material like paneling or sheetrock (maybe even insulated to reduce sound transmission when the wall section is shut) instead of glass.

I think the critical design element must be the sliding tracks that I would probably not be able to build myself. But I would guess that once I have the tracks, I could build myself a wall section to fasten to the tracks and accomplish the goal that way. I'm sure that using lighter materials for the moveable section of the wall would be important. Does anyone know of a sliding wall track product like this?

And any suggestions on the best way to implement this idea using typical wood building materials?

Comment: Google "pocket door" and "interior barn door".

Comment: One problem you might run in to, is where to put the "wall" when it's in the open position.  Commercial venues use wall sections that fold accordion style, to allow the "wall" to tuck away. @jack's solution is nice, because the opened "wall" takes up less space than the closed "wall".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have overseen the install of, and eventually tuned up a set of sliders that were 5 sections of glass panels 8 ft each. 2 of the panels, one at each end, were stationary, the other 3 were operable. Each panel weighed about 500 lbs each with 1 3/4" thick insulated glass panels. The wood frame was about 3" thick. The hardware was [lift-slide hardware](http://www.us.hoppe.com/products/lift-and-slide.html) The link is to the manufacturer that was used on this job, sorry the pic is crappy. It was shot from a long ways away.
[image: Pool pic]

The screen doors are in the way of the glass panels, but they are huge.

The point is I am trying to make with this is you don't need to use a glass door to do this with, although you can. It could very easily be a full wood panel as well.

The pic below shows another door system I did install from scratch, but the only picture I have that really shows anything, shows the bottom track and the panels. There are 6 panels in this wall (a different job than the other pic) 2 stationary and 4 operable. These doors were much lighter.
[image]

Comment: I think those look very nice. Thanks very much for the detailed answer, especially with photos. It is the kind of thing I imagined, but I was hoping/wondering if anyone has done something different from that. I'll be sure to accept your answer if I don't see another one soon. Thanks again!